# Script not posting input to PHP server script.

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, post

We are implementing a form on our site to let people subscribe their device. We use jquery.easing.js to only show certain fields when others are correct. The javascript is also validating input.

Now when it comes to sumbit, we want to sent two fields to our PHP script, so it can send us e-mail with subsciption.

The form is working, only we do not receive the email. We have looked into it but can't find a solution. Could someone help us?

Javascript (submit part):

```
$('#submit').click(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
var mac=$("#mac").val();
var store=$("#store").val();
//alert(mac);
//alert(store);
//
var dataString = 'mac=' + mac + 'store=' +store;
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'ajax/subscribe.php',
data: dataString,
success: function(data) {
  $("#optoutform").show().html("<h3>You have successfully opted-out.</h3>");
},
error: function(data) {
  $("#optoutform").show().html("<h3>There was an error processing your request.</h3>");
}
});
return valid;
});
```

Subscribe.php

```
$to = "request@domain.com"; 
$subject = "Request"; 
$mac = $_REQUEST['#mac'] ;
$store = $_REQUEST['#store'] ; 
$headers = "From: request@domain.com"; 
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $mac, $store, $headers) ;
```

Update:

Okay I have edited the subscribe.php to:

```
$to = "request@domain.com";
$subject = "Request";
$message = "<h1>Request</h1>";
$message .= "<strong>MAC</strong>: POST_$mac";
$message .= "<strong>Store</strong>: POST_$store";
$headers  = "From:youremail@domain.com";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
```

and have changed the dataString to the correct one, according to POST but still no email is sent to our inbox...

What else could we be doing wrong?

Comment: Your data is passing a string with field names `mac` and `store` but you're accessing `$_REQUEST['#mac']` and `$_REQUEST['#store']`.  This may not be the root of your problem, but wanted to point it out.

Comment: Your `mail()` has incorrect parameters, namely `$store` as it is in the position of `string $additional_headers`, and your `$headers = "From: request@domain.com";` are now in `string $additional_parameters` - [`bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: P.S. You may want to bind to the form id submit `$('#formId').submit(function...`, rather than click event so that people who press the enter key inside your form fields won't circumvent the click.

Comment: Thanks @Ross I have changed what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataString is incorrect, you forgot a '&' between vars :

```
var dataString = 'mac=' + mac + '&store=' + store;
```

Plus there is no need for a string, just pass an object, jQuery will do the rest :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/subscribe.php',
    data : {mac: mac, store: store},
    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ross stated, if you pass variables using POST method, use $_POST to access them.  Do not use $_REQUEST.  Also, your dataString variable is incorrect, you are forgetting the &, it should be:

```
var dataString = 'mac=' + mac + '&store=' +store;
```

Comment: okay I see, but even an email isn't sent to us. So that's more of an important issue. Do you have an solutions?

Comment: If yopu hit the subscribe.php page on its own, does it send an email?  Also, try this to help determine whether it's the mail function or some other problem:  if( $sent = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers) ){  echo "SENT";  } else {  echo "There was a problem"; }

Comment: I have used the ' if($sent ' and the script is returning SENT to me by browser, so I guess the script is functioning correctly.

Could it be a server side problem? I am on shared hosting..

Comment: Make sure the email address is correct, sounds silly,I know
Make sure its not ending up in spam
Thats all Ive got for you right now, try sending to a different email address maybe

Answer (score 0):

for POST method use

```
var dataString = {'mac':mac,'store':store};
```

for GET method use

```
var dataString = 'mac=' + mac + '&store=' + store;
```

Comment: okay @Salim I am using in the javascript the POST method, as well in the subscribe.php

Comment: Ok thanks so try, var dataString = {'mac':mac,'store':store};

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a hashtag in your PHP Request. Change

```
$mac = $_REQUEST['#mac'] ;
$store = $_REQUEST['#store'] ;
```

to

```
$mac = $_REQUEST['mac'] ;
$store = $_REQUEST['store'] ;
```

Also you need the & sign before setting another variable, so change

```
var dataString = 'mac=' + mac + 'store=' +store;
```

to

```
var dataString = 'mac=' + mac + '&store=' +store;
```

Comment: THanks guys for your response, I have changed the dataString and now the subscribe.php:

   `$to = "request@domain.com";
    $subject = "Request";
    $message = "<h1>Request</h1>";
    $message .= "<strong>MAC</strong>: REQUEST_$mac";
    $message .= "<strong>Store</strong>: REQUEST_$store";
    $headers  = "From:request@domain.com";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);`

But it still sends no email to our emailbox. What is still going wrong overhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is sending the mail, but not letting through the server.

If I am using PHPMailer icm SMTP. I am using gmail smtp setting and get this message back when activating subscribe.php:

Message could not be sent.
Error: SMTP Connect() failed.

`$mac = trim($_POST['mac']);
    $store = trim($_POST['store']);

```
$body = '<p>'.$mac.'<br />';
$body .= $store.'</p>';

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/include/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // vertel de class om SMTP te gebruiken
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";    
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // SMTP poort
$mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';  // eigen gmail-adres
$mail->Password = 'password';  // gmail wachtwoord
```

What is going wrong overhere (I am on shared hosting)